# Why can't create bundle.js file?

Tags: webpack

Why does main.js appear in the dist folder when I try to create a bundle.js file? I set the name of the bundle.js file, while it still remains minified, despite the fact that I wrote mode: 'development'

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

https://ibb.co/9rrF1vg
https://ibb.co/02s7Vjf